# Evaluate String "1+2^4*4*(4+4*9)-10"

Tags: python-2.7, parsing

I'm trying to evaluate this string. "1+2^4*4*(4+4*9)-10"

My strategy is to take each element, put it in a list, convert to the correct data type (int) or operator, concatenate and then evaluate. I'm trying to avoid using eval() and ast.literal_eval() was throwing a "malformed string error." I'm currently stuck at the point where I need to convert my operators from strings into operators.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
equation = ("1+2^4*4*(4+4*9)-10")

listint1 = 0
listint2 = 1
finallist = []
for elements in equation:
    finallist.append(equation[listint1:listint2])
    listint1 = listint1 + 1
    listint2 = listint2 + 1

finalfinallist = []
for element in finallist:
    if element.isdigit() == True:
        finalfinallist.append(int(element))
    else:
        finalfinallist.append(element)

for element in finalfinallist:
    if element == str:
        if element == "+":
            element = +
        elif element == "^":
            element = ^
        elif element == "*":
            element = *
        elif element == "("
            element = (
        elif element == ")":
            element = )
        elif element == "-"
            element = -


print finalfinallist
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Does this help ? https://gist.github.com/nava45/6333409#file-infix-expression-evaluation

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to build is a parser.  You can have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators.  Parsers are used to implement context free grammars, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar

I assume that by `2^4`you mean exponentiation, and not bitwise-xor (as per python operators).

There may be an ambiguity when trying to parse `2^4*4`, as it may be (2^4)*4 = 16 * 4 = 64, or `2^(4*4) = 2^16 = 65536`.  I do not know `ast`, but try looking at "associativity rules".

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to start with building an expression tree, for this kind of thing!

[Wikipedia: Expression Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree)

This would make handling the operators somewhat easier, this way you'll know when to expect an operator, and can do a string comparison to determine what operator to use on the operands in the expression tree!

Bear in mind, I've never had to do this in Python, only in C. So if there's a more Pythonic way to do this, I'm currently unaware, and would love to hear it.